# Servlet response in popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, popup

I have a JSP page which opens up a popup using JS.
The popup opens the following JSP page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="/ArchiveSearch/resources/css/messageDetail.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Message detail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Message Details</h1>
            <div class="messageMeta1">
                    <div><span class="label">Sender:</span> <c:out value="${messageid}" /></div>
                    <div><span class="label">Receiver:</span></div>
                    <div><span class="label">Subject:</span></div>
                    <div><span class="label">Attachments:</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageMeta2">
                    <div><span class="label">Case ID:</span></div>
                    <div><span class="label">Date:</span>${messagedate}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageContent">
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when JS opens the webpage the values that are passed from the servlet don't show up on the JSP page. But when I check HTML reponse under Firebug the HTML is rendered correctly. My question is how do I get the Servlet in the popup window correctly?

JS:

```
$('#searchResults tbody tr').live('dblclick', function () {
    var aData = table.fnGetData( this,0 );
    $.ajax({
        url: "MessageDetail",
        type: "POST",
        data: "messageid=" + aData,
        succes: function(data) {
        }
    });
    window.open(myjsppage.jsp, "_blank", "width=600,height=600");
});
```

Popup window has know knowledge of the request made before, how can I fix this?

**EDIT**
I tried something like this:

```
        succes: function(data) {
            gData = data;
        }
    });
    var popup = window.open("messageDetail.jsp", "_blank", "width=600,height=600");
    popup.document.write(gData);
});
```

I think I am on the right way, but i'm not completely there yet. Undefined is printed in the popup now, which means the variable isn't filled.

Comment: Which servlet? You open a popup which executes a JSP. If you want to invoke a servlet, the URL should be the URL of the servlet.

Comment: So, you make an AJAX call which returns HTML, and you would like to display this HTML in a popup, is that  right? I so, why don't you simply open a popup using the URL of your AJAX call, and remove the AJAX call completely?

Comment: I know, the servlet is already executed in the Ajax call. If the call is succesfull it return the correct html that I wanna display in a popup.

Comment: Just tried that in Firebug I get the correct HTML but in the browser I get an empty window

Comment: The URL must be MessageDetail?messageid=<aData>, and it will make a GET request insterad of a POST. If GET is not acceptable, then you'll need another strategy.

Comment: I did the ajax call cause that way I can add the parameters I need. Is this also possible when calling the servlet in the popup instantiation?

Comment: It is Post, I need to refresh more, haha

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good way of doing this, but if you want your code to work you must use it like this:

```
success: function(data) {
            gData = data;
            var popup = window.open("messageDetail.jsp", "_blank", "width=600,height=600");
            popup.document.write(gData);
        }
    });

});
```

Put your open code inside success method.

Also you wrote **success** with one 's', please fix it.